# how to convert a utf8 format nsstring to a regular nsstring?

Tags: c, ios4, objective-c-2.0, utf8-decode

i have a question that i get a NSString(*maybe i called it* **astring**) form a stream server 
when i print this astring ,shows`\u5f20\u9510\u7b49\u540c\u5fd7\u4efb` in console.

It's a NSString(**astring**) that can be printed to`\u5f20\u9510\u7b49\u540c\u5fd7\u4efb` by console ,
and is not such like a  `NSString* bstring=@"\u5f20\u9510\u7b49\u540c\u5fd7\u4efb"`

now, i want to convert this **astring** 
to a nsstring which may contains simple chinese character.
how could i do this? 
Thanks very much!
for more detail, the astring is`\\u5f20\\u9510\\u7b49\\u540c\\u5fd7\\u4efb` in memory

Comment: There’s no need to convert anything. `@"\u5f20\u9510\u7b49\u540c\u5fd7\u4efb"` is the same as `@"张锐等同志任"`. Maybe you could edit your question and paste the code you’re using, which would help us understand why you would need conversion.

Comment: So the string you’re receiving from the server is actually `@"\\u5f20\\u9510\\u7b49\\u540c\\u5fd7\\u4efb"`?

Comment: how are you getting the content?

Comment: @Bavarious i used asihttp,get a respond nsdata,then convert to nsstring,that is what i get now

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *aString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"\u5f20\u9510\u7b49\u540c\u5fd7\u4efb"];
NSLog(@"%@", aString);
```

This should work right?

Comment: oh,thanks ,but it's not what i want to.i have edit my question,let you know clear.